# Are there any languages in which 'knowledge' is not a mass noun?

Tags: semantics, cross-linguistic, list-of-languages, lexical-semantics, countability

I would have thought there would be some, but I'd love some examples. So are there any languages in which the translation of 'knowledge'is not a mass noun?

Comment: Absolutely. This is true in many Slavonic languages. E.g., Russian: `знание` (singular) has meaning of "knowing that…", while 'знания` (plural) is basically an equivalent of English "knowledge". In some of these languages, however, singular and plural forms match, however they are different when being inflected by noun case.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can in fact be plural in most European languages.

In French, Italian, German, Spanish, Russian et altri there are *connaissances*, *conoscenze*, *Kenntnisse*, *conocimientos*, *знания*... which are typically plural and translated into English as *knowledge* in many contexts.

Note that most Germanic and Latin languages have a distinction between *connaitre* and *savoir*.  These words all share a root with the former, distinct from the root of *wisdom*, cognates and translations of which can also be countable in some of these languages.

Comment: You are right with what you said; but I'd like to clarify that *knowledge* can indeed be a mass noun in those languages, e.g. the most general translation of "knowledge" for German would be *Wissen*, which is a mass noun. What is correct is that there are words related to the concept of knowledge that do have countable status, but saying "**it** is plural in most European languages" is a little misleading as the English *knowledge* has more than one translation (I think the English term is a more general one, used for both *connaitre* and *savoir* / *kennen* and *wissen*, as you pointed out).

Comment: (Probably most, maybe all of those languages also have a corresponding mass noun, if they have the count noun).

Comment: s/ *is* / *can be*.  Feel free to edit directly.

Comment: "Cognizioni" is not the translation of knowledge, *conoscenza* is. At best, it'd be "cognizione" in the sense of "understanding".

Comment: @Alenanno I should have ignored the dictionary.  My intuition said *le mie conoscenze di ...* is a valid phrase.  True?

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer Mmmh yeah, I think it might work. :)